# Trouble running Simplenote 1.0 client for Linux from Automattic

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

Has anyone successfully installed *and run* the 1.0.0 [Simplenote client](http://simplenote.com/) for Linux recently released by Automattic?

I grabbed the DEB and installed via the Software Centre. It installed successfully (the system reported), and <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> search finds it ... but it simply won't run. Nothing.

I then re-installed with the GDebi Package installer, with the same outcome.

Is it just me? I'm on 14.04 LTS, though hopefully that's not a factor here.

(I would be happy to add any log files for diagnosis, but I'll need some prompts for that.)

---

**Update** - after checking some things (with thanks to @AlinAndrei) I tried a simple reboot ... and now it runs, and runs well. That was a very odd experience, and the "fixit-by-reboot" technique isn't something I'm accustomed to on Ubuntu. Still, good to know that all is well.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you've installed the package on a 32bit Ubuntu installation. Even though the Simplenote website or the deb filename don't mention this, the deb is only available for 64bit.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm on a 64-bit system. `:(` I take, however, that it works for you. Thanks for checking!